# Merging two dataframes which has duplicated 'on' value on one side

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, and the standard dataframe has some same values(=id) which i have to use as merging point.

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id | res_number |    type    | payment    | 
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  a |     1      |    toys    | 20000      |
|  a |     2      |  clothing  | 30000      |
|  a |     3      |    food    | 40000      |
|  b |     4      |    food    | 40000      |
|  c |     5      |   laptop   | 30000      |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

\I want to merge this dataframe with below dataframe.

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id |   group    | unique_num | 
+----+------------+------------+
|  a |     1      |    1231    | 
|  b |     2      |    1234    | 
|  c |     1      |    1241    | 
+----+------------+------------+
```

and i want to make dataframe like this.

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| id | res_number |    type    | payment    |   group    | unique_num |
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  a |     1      |    toys    | 20000      |      1     |    1231    |
|  a |     2      |  clothing  | 30000      |      1     |    1231    |
|  a |     3      |    food    | 40000      |      1     |    1231    |
|  b |     4      |    food    | 40000      |      2     |    1234    |
|  c |     5      |   laptop   | 30000      |      3     |    1241    |
+----+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

As you can notice i want to merge dataframes with 'id', but the standard dataframe has some same values on 'id'. My target is just pasting values whatever values on 'id' has.

Can you give me good example of this problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `group` in the last row should be `1` and not `3`.

Comment: You can define the on keyword to be "left" if you only want to preseve the values of the left dataframe. "right" if you only want to preserve the values of the right dataframe. "inner" if you only want to preserve values which occure in both dataframes, and "outer" if you want to preserve all values

Comment: Thank you. now i got to understand about 'left', 'right', 'inner', 'outer' :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with `left` join:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left')
```

Or if possible more common columns names in both `DataFrames`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='id')
```

---

```
print (df)
  id  payment  res_number      type  group  unique_num
0  a    20000           1      toys      1        1231
1  a    30000           2  clothing      1        1231
2  a    40000           3      food      1        1231
3  b    40000           4      food      2        1234
4  c    30000           5    laptop      1        1241
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)